# How to count values in columns in a data.frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, count, sum, histogram

I have a data.frame with vegetation in a presence-abscence matrix and ELLENBERG-values about moisture (values 1-9 and indicator plants (! and =)). Now I want to count the plants in every column (observation point) and for each ELLENBERG-value.

T1 -T4 are my observation points and when the plant is present, the value is `1`, if absent `0`. In F_nr are my ELLENBERG Values from 1 to 9. In F_sym the indicators with `!` and `=`. In my output I count the values, i. e. in T1 I have one plants with `4`, two with `7`, one with `!` and one with `=`.

Here some small example data:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- df2 <- data.frame(name=c("Acer campestre", "Acer negundo",    "Achillea millefolium agg.", "Agrostis stolonifera", "Alnus glutinosa", "Alnus incana"),
                        T1=rbinom(6, 1, .5), T2=rbinom(6, 1, .5), T3=rbinom(6, 1, .5), T4=rbinom(6, 1, .5), 
                        F_Nr=c(5,6,4,7,9,7), F_sym=c(NA, NA, NA, "!","=", "="))
```

I excpect a matrix like this, to create plots about the distribution of the values.

```
df_count <- data.frame(F_sum=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,"=", "!"), 
                       T1=c(0,0,0,1,0,0,2,0,0,1,0), 
                       T2=c(0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0),
                       T3=c(0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1),
                       T4=c(0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0))
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: I don't understand how the expected output was derived from the input, i.e. how did `F_nr` go from `0 1 1 0` to `1 0 0 1`, etc.?

Comment: T1 -T4 are my observation points and when the plant ist present, the value is `1`, if not `0`. In F_nr are my ELLENBERG Values from 1 to 9. In F_sym the indicators with `!`and `=`. In my output I count the values, i. e. in T4 I have two plants with `7`and two with `=`and one with `!` and so on. Does this explain my question?

Comment: Are you sure you're using the right seed?  When I use `seed(1)` T4 contains 0 and 0 for the two `7`s, 1 and 0 for the two `=`s, and 0 for `!`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use a combination of `aggregate()` and `merge()`.

```
df2 <- read.table(text="
                        name T1 T2 T3 T4 F_Nr F_sym
            'Acer campestre'  0  1  1  0    5  <NA>
              'Acer negundo'  0  1  0  1    6  <NA>
 'Achillea millefolium agg.'  1  1  1  1    4  <NA>
      'Agrostis stolonifera'  1  0  0  0    7     !
           'Alnus glutinosa'  0  0  1  1    9     =
              'Alnus incana'  1  0  1  0    7     =",
              header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

fnr <- aggregate(df2[,2:5], list(df2$F_Nr), sum)
fsm <- aggregate(df2[,2:5], list(df2$F_sym), sum)
counts0 <- rbind(fnr, fsm)

dtf <- data.frame(F_sum=c(1:9, "=", "!"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

counts <- merge(dtf, counts0, by.x="F_sum", by.y="Group.1", all.x=TRUE)

counts[is.na(counts)] <- 0
counts[match(dtf$F_sum, counts$F_sum), ]
#    F_sum T1 T2 T3 T4
# 3      1  0  0  0  0
# 4      2  0  0  0  0
# 5      3  0  0  0  0
# 6      4  1  1  1  1
# 7      5  0  1  1  0
# 8      6  0  1  0  1
# 9      7  2  0  1  0
# 10     8  0  0  0  0
# 11     9  0  0  1  1
# 2      =  1  0  2  1
# 1      !  1  0  0  0
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great, my data.frame is large enough, so that I can finish after creating `counts0`.

Comment: @Nesch: Ok. I noticed there's a discrepancy between my `counts` and your `df_count` in the `=` row. I assumed the observation should be summed here as well?